# Optimize $group performance in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grouping

I have huge documents about 2 millions like this, each account has many logs

```
{ 
        "_id" : 1, 
        "type" : "login",  
        "date" : "2057-03-28T02:59:41.176Z", 
        "link" : DBRef("accounts", ObjectId("5bd9683d4df859ad279b5649"))
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 2, 
        "type" : "login",  
        "date" : "2057-03-28T02:53:41.176Z", 
        "link" : DBRef("accounts", ObjectId("5bd9683d4df859ad279b5649"))
    },
    { 
        "_id" : 3, 
        "type" : "login",  
        "date" : "2057-03-28T02:49:41.176Z", 
        "link" : DBRef("accounts", ObjectId("5bd9683d4df859ad279b5643"))
    }
```

I'm trying to get latest date of log per account by this way, but it took couple seconds to get result.

```
db.logs.aggregate(
    {
        $match: {
          "link.$ref": "accounts",
          "link.$id": { $in: [ObjectId("5bd9683d4df859ad279b5649"), ObjectId("5bd9683d4df859ad279b5643")]} //array accounts id
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$link",
            date: {$last: "$date"},
            type: {$last: "$type"}
        }
    }
)
```

I'm using mongodb 3.4